# My Nivo slider doesn't loads on Chrome Or IE

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, wordpress

Nivo slider loads in firefox only now and i tried all the solutions that helped others like putting a width and a height for the slider and adding latest jquery link in header. but still doesn't want to appear.
This is a link to my site :

http://www.travisblacklaw.com/

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: You've added jQuery at least two times, and the version used is 1.6.4 which throws an error as `on()` is not supported in that version etc.

Answer (score 0):

- You are loading jquery 2 times in your website, keep the latest and
  remove the `1.6.4`

> ```
> <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
> <script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.travisblacklaw.com/wp-content/themes/theme05/js/jquery-1.6.4.min.js?ver=1.6.4'></script>
> ```

- `gprofiles.js` is using `jquery.on` which is not found in `1.6.4`

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'on'

- Multiple Javascript errors since it seems you are using ajax to call
  a URL which is not in the same domain as yours. only `jquery.JSONP`
  can call external URLs.

> Blocked a frame with origin "http://www.linksalpha.com" from accessing
>   a frame with origin "http://www.travisblacklaw.com". Protocols,
>   domains, and ports must match.